# Google Analytics Mobile : strange active users number

Tags: mobile, google-analytics

I'm experiencing some strange statistics with google analytics for mobile.

Day-1 active users are decreasing during the day 0.

Example : Yesterday i had 3100 DL of my app, GA shows me 5,923 active users for this day (logical since i have existing users : 20K).

BUT during the day, this number decrease to 2900 active users. WTF ?

Every day, it's the same thing, my active users are set one time and fall down after (even under my day-1 downloads)

Anyone can give me a clue ?

Thanks :)

Note : I don't edit any segment, it's always on 100% of sessions.